# Is there a way to get a tag from a specific commit in git?

Tags: git, tagging, git-tag

How do I get the git tag(s) on a specific git commit SHA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *--contains* param.

Example:
To see what tags are on the SHA *abcd1234*, from the shell:

```
git tag --contains abcd1234
```

which returns the name of the tag

```
v1.1
```

If there are multiple tags on that specific commit, you'll get them back separated by newlines:

```
v1.1
LATEST_STABLE
MY-TAG
```

To set this in an environment variable via a bash script:

```
export GIT_TAG=`git tag --contains $MY_SHA`
```